# Suddenly I'm getting email from Stack Exchange about some (but not all) recent comments

Tags: bug

This has happened 3 times only, and only recently. The header of the most recent says

> *Inbox
>
> The following items were added to your inbox since you last checked it on 2023-02-09*

I long ago turned off all email updates from my SE accounts, so this is surprising.
What happened and how do I get it to stop?

I already have internal notification and
don't want email.

This is coming from Stack Overflow (`do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email`), not any particular SE account.

EDIT:

The "Edit email settings" link at the bottom links now to:

> "https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=FhKQFemTFIJzn5ywFPMHvmfTNQuHch-2BdBSRMIU5hUkReW4X67eTxz6cyYHejzGsLZHEoNaaS1eCrS-2BP8MOQIm74jE4O5nUccYzZP0E0qBLpeUx9R67jSzxnMU7-2FTP0-2BJ3lA9LoJVt86Oif4Uh4xjIao1xQuI6OYQza7qOO2eEdn1N1uCpeK-2BAJ2jE7G8o3HJgfVN6FjlQFRG-2BF5EonQ5nXwcXd6rvTWSL3rgrPaWuUADIOSNvoQb3BVZc5EsU9ycij7d_zpp1eARwN6NsGC-2BW-2FrNsFUCeUicX5oSj5xLOaSJhBgXIb-2B3gOSve9w14J68KAN4bGIqONxFrlyp2v2G-2FK12KelrmM6JrjjbmpGMmkV-2F8dkxIGojWHoBciOxwBN5vlVVEx-2Fxv-2BUh2zvZ6M28IMBcHOKbJlm3IlKcbF-2F156KAg9Pb2dkAwCAwDyYB5ojHxX0Osg04E7eNCCgpwjkQQmQSp1zr7HTa2je6qENO-2BNcPzYdZInGeOYohpZXfc5PCpoOEfJF1cL3TsC8kTDvhKS501G1WJAnhs8260EPlxg5Lb1ew2fU3vQN-2B43w5B908Smvw-2BGwAJrDp7bVvlot5ci4PAQgb5k1-2Bg-2FIupiiLF59RvTKP1lQqBql4xSdjCCuFAGjzEfl5fIR0mDxrGgDE5NLumCKiUWo6dyS0s59hK5FJa3MfLjhtE8v8RyW57YWIAAy9UlmEODoeZWLMe6rQzXp2HgbPwqP0-2B-2F6Q7VFRXakcrMYm-2BXKQYbQ61mTmldlmEFyRTXZw2mDf516G3ysJVRVoZPw-3D-3D"

-- though who knows what it linked to then? -- and when I clicked on it, I got a 404 originally. Now that I apparently have inadvertently joined a new group and created an account, it sent me to my new account page on Stack Overflow, where I found that some of the mail notification tags were open, and closed them.

Insha'allah, this will solve the problem, but not the mystery of why it turned on in the first place.

Comment: Surely, this would be a setting on your profile (email settings) that you can change. Obviously can't explain why it's on all of a sudden, but that shouldn't stop you from turning it off

Comment: I have never used StackOverflow, nor set any settings. When I followed the link on the email to change my mail settings, I got a 404. I've never gotten any mail at all from StackOverflow, except an automatic congratulation when I went over a big point limit last year.

Comment: it's entirely possible this has nothing to do with stackoverflow, the community, and instead this email is a standard one used by stackoverflow, the company.

Comment: So I hafta contact the company?

Comment: No, just go to your profile email settings on any network. They all share the same email settings.

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide the URL of the unsubscribe link that 404-ed?

Answer (score 5):

In your settings, there's an [email settings tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current), with an inbox option:

[image: inbox: Answers to your questions, comments, chat notifications, and more]

It probably got turned on when they changed the available options for email.

Note that this has nothing to do with Stack Overflow, though SO has more email options. You can change this setting on [any site](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) (that's not even a picture of Stack Overflow above).

Comment: Thank you. I set everything to OFF, but I had to join SO and create an account to do so.